# How exactly Git repository associated with Perforce repository?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, perforce, p4v

When I create a workspace on my local machine taking latest version from Perforce using Perforce Visual Client connected to some server. 
Open solution through VS2015. Files are locked and when I try to edit I get pop up as

"Source Control- Git Do you want to edit file..?"

As per my knowledge Git is different repository altogether whereas I see googling that they are used somehow together for moving repository from one to another but here I am not doing that nor explicitly I added any plug in related to Git.

Could be client was using Git Repository earlier and top of it Perforce (P4V) is used

But exactly if Perforce and Git are two different entities
 Are Perforce and Git linked? How they are associated and work together?
 why the Git related popup appears?

Appreciate help in understanding the actual working. Thanks in Advance

Comment: I'm not very familiar with it but.. 1. What is the "Current source control plug-in" selected in the Tools->Options->"Source Control" tab. 2. Open your solution file (`*.sln`) with text editor and check is there a section starting with `GlobalSection(SourceCodeControl)`, and what does it contain

Comment: Also, what Git-related extensions you have installed in the visual studio? Sometimes they ignore the settings

Comment: @max630 Current Source control plugin  is - Git and I see sln file with GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms)

Comment: You did not say what exactly the `GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms)` says. Does it mention git? You copy copy it to the answer removing private fields like paths, hostnames etc.